# What is the iPad mini user agent?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-mini

What is the iPad mini user agent?

How to distinguish between iPad and iPad mini?

Comment: A Google search isn't really turning anything up. We might have to just wait until it comes out.

Answer (score 4):

The iPad Mini has the same resolution of iPad 2, and it shouldn't be a retina display so you can get that info by JavaScript with this code:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
    // retina display...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that iPad 2 has the same resolution, it's the 3rd and 4th gen iPads that have retina displays.  That may be exactly what you are saying here, but if so, it needs clarification.

Comment: Can anyone clarify this answer, or confirm that `devicePixelRatio` disambiguates between iPad mini (v1) and iPad 2? From what I can tell, they seem identical in every way, programmatically speaking.

Comment: @aaaidan: This code does not distinguish my ipad mini from my ipad.

Answer (score 4):

On my 16 gig iPad mini [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) returned:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A406 Safari/8536.25

Answer (score 1):

Regarding detecting iPad mini (vs iPad 2), [this article](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ipad-mini-detection-for-html5-user-agent) suggests that **there is no way** to programmatically determine whether you're running on an iPad mini (v1) vs an iPad 2. This seems to be a very deliberate choice by Apple.

I'd be delighted to be proven wrong. Anyone know any better?

Answer (score 0):

console output of Navigator:

```
Navigator
appCodeName: "Mozilla"
appName: "Netscape"
appVersion: "5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A406 Safari/8536.25"
cookieEnabled: true
geolocation: Geolocation
language: "en-us"
mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray
onLine: true
platform: "iPad"
plugins: PluginArray
product: "Gecko"
productSub: "20030107"
standalone: false
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A406 Safari/8536.25"
vendor: "Apple Computer, Inc."
vendorSub: ""
__proto__: NavigatorPrototype
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the info from my 32GB iPad Mini in case it'll help anyone:

```
32GB iPad Mini
Version 8.0.2 (12A405)
Model ME280LL/A
```

My User Agent according to WhatsMyUserAgent.com:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X)
AppleWebKit/60.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0
Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4
```